# Computing Posterior via Particle Filter

Tags: particle-filter

I have a question regarding the computation of the posterior using particle filter. I start reporting details from [https://cse.sc.edu/~terejanu/files/tutorialMC.pdf](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Eterejanu/files/tutorialMC.pdf)

Consider random processes $(Q_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}},(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$, where each $X_{t}:\Omega \rightarrow V$ and $Q_{t}:\Omega \rightarrow V$ is a random variable. Let $f: \Omega \times \Omega \rightarrow V$ be a function. Assume $X_{t+1} = f(X_{t},Q_{t})$. The set $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ denotes a set of states.

Then, the link explains how to compute $E[f(X_{t},Q_{t})]$, by evaluating $\sum_{i=1}^{N} W(x_{t}^{i}) f(x_{t}^{i},q_{t})$ for particles (that is realizations) $x_{t}^{i}$ with corresponding weights $W(x_{t}^{i})$ (using the law of large numbers).

However from my understanding the filtering task is about to compute the most likely state given the observations, that is to compute $\max_{x \in V} P(X_{t}=x | z_{1:t})$, where $z_{1:t}$ are the observations for time 1 up to time t.

So how do I use the sampled expected value to solve the filter task ?  Is the idea to use $f(x,q):= x$ so that we compute $E[X_t]$ ? But that would not be the same as $\max P(X_{t}=x | z_{1:t})$.

Comment: I rewrote the question post I had before, but now focused to one question at a time.